# How to dynamically plot various graphs

Tags: javascript, html

How to dynamically plot different graphs using javascript in html pages. At runtime the value will be got from some function.

Also comparison of different parameters to be done.

Please help me out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110964/open-source-client-side-javascript-based-2d-data-plotting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is a pure Javascript plotting library for jQuery you should check out.

See [some AJAX examples](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/)